# Passing a nullptr to my overloaded function causes a runtime error

Tags: c++, overloading, using-directives

To understand more using directives and function overloading I've tried this program:

```
namespace ns{
    void f(int){cout << "int\n";}
    void f(double){cout << "double\n";}
    void f(std::string){cout << "string\n";}
    struct Foo{};
}

void f(ns::Foo const&){
    cout << "ns::Foo\n";
}

namespace bin{
    void f(int*){
        std::cout << "bin::f(int*)\n";
    }
}


int main(){

    using namespace ns;
    //using namespace bin;

    f(7); // int
    f(7.5); // double

    f(ns::Foo{}); // ns::Foo

    try{
        f(nullptr);
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e){
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I run the program, it works fine, except for the last call to `f(nullptr)` which causes a runtime error:

```
int
double
ns::Foo
basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

If I un-comment the `using` directive for namespace `bin`, then the code works fine.

```
using namespace bin;
```

The output:

```
int
double
ns::Foo
bin::f(int*)
```

Comment: `void f(std::string)` will erroneously try and convert `char*` to `std::string`.

Comment: You can unfortunately do the same thing with `f(0)`. Any other number will be caught by the compiler as an illegal integer-to-string conversion, but the historical relationship between `NULL` and 0 gets in the way here.

Comment: when using namespace bin your f(int*) is better match (no conversion) and then the fact that string( const char* ) errors does not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `using namespace bin;` is commented out, there is only 1 version of `f()` available that can take a `nullptr` as input. `nullptr` is not implicitly convertible to `int` or `double`, so `ns::f(int)` and `ns::f(double)` are ruled out. But `std::string` can be constructed from a `const char*`, and `nullptr` is implicitly convertible to `const char*`, so the compiler can construct a temporary `std::string` object to pass to `ns::f(std::string)`.  However, it is *undefined behavior* to construct a `std::string` from a null `const char*`, hence the runtime error (which is NOT guaranteed, BTW, as the behavior is *undefined*, so *anything* can happen).

When `using namespace bin;` is not commented out, there are 2 versions of `f()` available that can take a `nullptr` as input.  `bin::f(int*)` is a better match than `ns::f(std::string)`, as `nullptr` is implicitly convertible to `int*`, so there is no need to construct a temporary object, thus the compiler chooses to call `bin::f(int*)` instead of `ns::f(std::string)`.

Comment: Ok Thank you. So you mean that `std::string` constructor that takes a constant character string always de-reference that argument (`char const*`)?

So I think that that string constructor checks its argument (pointer) for a null-terminator as a sing of end of string that is why it de-reference it even being null? So a possible implementation r overload of that ctor is to provide a separate argument as the size. At that point we can decide to de-reference or not that pointer. (if 0 don't de-reference otherwise do it)? are my thought correct?

Comment: And that constructor takes a single pointer to character string (`std::string(char const*);`) and is not `explicit` to allow Implicit Conversion for (char const* to std::string) through Copy-Initialization for a const char* e.g `std::string str = "Hi there!";` ?

Comment: What the `std::string(const char*)` constructor does when it is given a null pointer is **undefined**.  It MAY dereference the pointer, or it MAY NOT. That is up to the implementation to decide. If you want to avoid this issue, you could provide an `ns::f(const char*)` overload and check for null yourself. But then you will have an ambiguity error if `using namespace bin;` is used, unless you explicitly typecast the `nullptr` to `char*` to `int*`.

Comment: So you mean the implementation is responsible on how to initialize data members of class `std::string` from a pointer to char `char const*`?

Comment: Yes, the standard does not say what the `std::string` constructor must do, so the implementation can do whatever it wants. Some implementations treat a null pointer as a 0-length string. Some don't.